# How to create an undirected table of this data?

Tags: r, excel

Data set:

[image: data.frame]

The 1 indicates the variable is true. I need a table with every possible connection for each case (undirected):

[image]

How can I do this in R for all 3887 cases? How could I export my data into an Excel file?

Comment: Hello People, I often saw (and experienced myself) that very complex problems get a lot of attention. That means that there is a lot of knowledge and engagement here. So this question did not get a lot of attention so far. A lot of views but no answers. Can someone explain me: Is the question clear enough? Does the problem make sense? Why is there a lack of attention and support and what can I do better? Thanks a lot

Comment: Generally, the questions that get answered quickly are ones that are easy to work on--and one of the best ways to make a question easy to work on is to include a copy/pasteable reproducible example. As it is now, if I wanted to work on your problem, I'd need to manually try to recreate your input based on your picture. If instead you provided code to create the input, I could copy/paste it into my R session and work on the interesting part: the solution.

Comment: The easiest way to create copy/pasteable sample data is with `dput`. If your data frame is named `my_data`, then `dput(my_data[1:10, 1:8])` will give copy/pasteable code to create the first 10 rows and 8 columns.

Comment: For more info, see the FAQ on [How to make a great reproducible example in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Or for practical examples if you look at the [R question queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) and click on answered questions, I think you'll see that most of them have copy/pasteable reproducible examples.

Comment: It looks like an adjacency matrix which will be used to generate an adjacency list, to be used with to Gephi. Is that right? Please apart from the comments above, add the purpose of your data and how you plan to use them with Gephi